# false positives in rkhunter with hidden ports

Tags: linux, security, monitoring, network-monitoring

We got rkhunter checking our systems and are running the full check, except deleted_files and suspscan. So the network check is running too.

This network check searches for hidden ports. So ports which are found by unhide-tcp but do not appear in netstat.

We have occasionally a warning message, which says a hidden port was found. But when I check this port manually with telnet or rerun the check with unhide and rkhunter, this port never appears to be open. The ports are allways in a range above 1200.

This is how the warning looks:

```
Warning: Hidden ports found:
     Port number: TCP:12645
```

I suspect the cause in a race condition somewhere in "unhide".

- Does anyone has experienced the same behavior?
- How can I avoid this "false positives" ?

Comment: Please check with  ss -lt,

netstat -tanp,

lsof +c 0 -iTCP | grep -i listen

Comment: I ran these commands about 1 minutes after a the rkhunter run with this warning. Same result. The port was not open anymore. 

`Warning: Hidden ports found:
         Port number: TCP:44223
`

Comment: Try to reboot system it may solve your problem ?

Comment: I am having this alarms too, in my case all the ports are in the net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range range, I am thinking that these are false alarms...